# Terminal cannot recognize 'service' command to check the status of tor. How an it be resolved?

Tags: bash, terminal, kali-linux, services, tor

I wrote this code on the linux terminal:-

```
test@kali:~$ service tor status
bash: service: command not found
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I don't know kali, but it might use `systemctl status tor` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You got the error

```
bash: service: command not found
```

because the command `service` could not be found. (thank you @JdeBP)

```
whereis service
```

Will show you where it is (probably)

```
/usr/sbin/service
```

You can add '/usr/sbin` to your $PATH

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
```

As @PierreAlainToret explains, if `service` had executed properly then you should have got a different error because you are running `systemd`

```
Unit tor.service could not be found.
```

Comment: `service` does not need superuser privileges merely to obtain status, and lack of superuser privileges does not result in a command not found error.  Lack of an appropriate path that includes the `sbin` directories does that.

Comment: @JdeBP It does on my Kali box. Tested before posting. The initial error message from bash was that the command `service` was not found, whereas running it with `sudo` finds the command but fails to find the `tor.service`

Comment: Now look at your path in both cases.

Comment: @JdeBP I just did and edited accordingly. My thanks for your correction

Answer (score 0):

From this [page](https://kali.training/chapter-5/managing-services/), you have to use systemd to configure Kali Linux.

So the command `systemctl` would replace `service`, and your example will become `systemctl status tor.service` or as .service are automatically added in systemd `systemctl status tor`